# Using moment.js, JS, or Jquery, turn on a feature within a time frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, momentjs

I'm trying to write code that will reliably show a div between certain times.

I'm using moment.js and they claim in the docs that they can help do this but I can't find the proper way to query the times I need.

My code that will give you an idea of what I want doesn't really work because when I try to turn on or off the feature, if the time goes before midnight, I end up with negative numbers instead of time. (I am using UTC times and subtracting 10 hours. I can use negative numbers in my arrays but for clarity, I'd like to stick with actual times as much as possible.)

Also, the way my code is now, i can turn off the feature at a time but turning it off after a time would be better, having it on between times would be the best.

Would you guys know how to properly query moment( ).isAfter or .isBetween with time rather than dates?

So far I've tried many permutations of:

```
moment().isBetween('7:00:00', '8:00:00', 'hour', 'minute'); and .isAfter.
```

The docs don't seem to have examples for this and no one on the web has posed the question in the past.  Thanks!

```
var openSun = [6,7,17,22]; // on hours

// Sundays ---------------------------------------------- //
// setup sunday - on
if (moment().days() === 7) {
    for (var i = 0; i < openSun.length; i++) {
        if (openSun[i] === moment().utc().hours()-10) {
            $('#cast').hide();
            $('#cast-on').show();
        } 
    }
}

// switch back to off
var offhoursSun = [8,17,22];
var offminutesSun = [00,30,30];

for (var j = 0; j < offhoursSun.length; j++) {

    if ((moment.utc().hours()-10 === offhoursSun[j]) && (moment.utc().minutes() === offminutesSun[j])) {
      $('#cast').show();
      $('#cast-on').hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a task like this you could just use vanilla javascript to solve it.

First I would recommend to use a better and more generalized data structure to store your timeslots. I would prefer it like this:

```
var openSun = [
    {
        start: {
            hour: 7,
            minute: 0,
        },
        end: {
            hour: 8,
            minute: 0,
        },
    },
    {
        start: {
            hour: 17,
            minute: 0,
        },
        end: {
            hour: 17,
            minute: 30,
        },
    },
    {
        start: {
            hour: 22,
            minute: 0,
        },
        end: {
            hour: 22,
            minute: 30,
        },
    }
];
```

Then you could just run through defined time slots and check if you are actually between the boundaries of one:

```
$(function(){
    var start, end, now;
    var d = new Date();

    now = d.getHours()*60+d.getMinutes();
    $('#cast').show();
    $('#cast-on').hide();



    if (d.getDay() === 0) {
        for (var slot = 0, len = openSun.length; slot < len; slot++) {
            start = openSun[slot].start.hour*60+openSun[slot].start.minute;
            end = openSun[slot].end.hour*60+openSun[slot].end.minute;
            if (now>start && now<end){
                $('#cast').hide();
                $('#cast-on').show();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

});
```

Feel free to check the code at http://jsfiddle.net/yLy8ocd5/

I used your data. To make the example work just change it so you fit into a time slot.

**EDIT:** this is how it works with moment.js:

```
$(function(){
    var start, end;

    $('#cast').show();
    $('#cast-on').hide();   


    if (moment().weekday() === 0) {
        for (var slot = 0, len = openSun.length; slot < len; slot++) {
            start = moment({
                hour: openSun[slot].start.hour, 
                minute: openSun[slot].start.minute
            });

            end = moment({
                hour: openSun[slot].end.hour, 
                minute: openSun[slot].end.minute
            });

            if (moment().isBetween(start, end)){
                $('#cast').hide();
                $('#cast-on').show();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Ah I see what you've done here. I like how you multiplied the hours by 60 as well so we don't have to deal with the time conversion. I tried going the vanilla route first but I didn't know how to handle the times. As an aside, I still would like a moment.js answer just out of curiosity but yours is definitely an answer. I'll mark it so after leaving it open a little longer, thanks!

Comment: @nyhunter: I added a snippet containing the same solution using moment.js. But if you should not have any more complicated date/time concerning tasks to solve or any sort of localizing of date/time values to do, I do not see why you should prefer the use of a library over simple vanilla js.

Comment: Thanks, I originally posed this question because I thought with moment.js, my code could be condensed to a line or 2, I have to do this for weekdays and Saturdays too. I now know that I can just add those times and days to the variable object though and forget about using arrays. Much cleaner. But, I was hoping to get 3 lines similar to: if (current time) isBetween(open, close){turn on}, that would do it... I was turned on to moment bc I used it a while back and it did great simplifying my code. I guess it still can't do this yet? Thanks again!

Comment: well you could leave out the start and end variables and put their definitions into the isBetween check and the $('#cast').show(); in the beginning is basically redundant. You would save about 10 lines of code, but the way it is its much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried passing a new date JavaScript to momentjs between and is after? I see you are using strings in date values

Comment: Do you mean where i have times as strings in the query? The example on their site is     moment('2010-10-20').isBetween('2010-10-19', '2010-10-25'); // true. But they say if no date is entered, it will default to current time for the first one and the query can be used for times as well as dates. I guess I'm just using it incorrectly. I don't need dates though because this event will happen every sunday which I will have taken care of - I have to add (moment().days() === 7) to the latter for. (sorry for the format here, I don't know how to edit my answer so it looks nicely formatted)

Comment: Sorry, StackOverflow won't let me edit again, this was the example I wanted to quote:    moment('2010-10-20').isBetween('2010-01-01', '2012-01-01', 'year');.